# Programar online e de forma compartilhada

Tags: c++

Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me indicar (se existir) alguma plataforma online de programação C++ para que duas ou mais pessoas possam programar em tempo real e compartilhar esse programa entre elas? Tenho um grupo de trabalho e queremos programar e editar ao mesmo tempo, cada um desenvolvendo uma parte do código, de forma online...isso é possível? Podem me dizer uma plataforma?

Comment: o Visual Studio 2019 tem um recurso chamado Live Share que aparentemente faz isso, mas não cheguei a usar

Comment: https://repl.it/languages/cpp, no menu à esquerda há a opção "Multiplayer"

Comment: Tinh o http://c9.io que era muito interessante e com edição multiuser, mas depois que a Amazon comprou ficou extremamente burocrático acessar a interface.

Answer (score 2):

> [Repl.it](https://repl.it/) gives you an instant IDE to learn, build, collaborate, and host all in one place.

[Repl.it](https://repl.it/) é um ambiente de programação online, possui um debugger e muitas outras ferramentas que ajudam a programar.

É possível utilizar [diversas linguagens](https://repl.it/languages), incluindo [C++](https://repl.it/languages/cpp), e é possível que duas ou mais pessoas programem no mesmo projeto em tempo real, compartilhando esse programa entre elas e conversando num chat: [repl.it - multiplayer](https://repl.it/site/blog/multi).

[Vídeo que mostra as funcionalidades do repl.it multiplayer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZ3yPLNeiqs).

Criar uma conta no [repl.it](https://repl.it/) é gratuito, no entanto, na versão gratuita, todos programas são públicos. Para que os programas desenvolvidos sejam privados, e só tornados públicos se o utilizador assim o desejar, é necessário pagar pela versão "Premium". De qualquer forma, [repl.it](https://repl.it/) é uma ferramenta muito poderosa, mesmo sem a versão "Premium".

O IDE do [repl.it](https://repl.it/) tem a seguinte apresentação:

[image: IDE do repl.it para C++]

Answer (score -1):

o que nós costumamos usar é o versionador de projetos.

Sendo este uma ferramenta que gerencia toda a vida de um dado projeto, guardando o histórico, ou versão, de cada documento do projeto. Lembrando que documento pode ser qualquer coisa, uma imagem, um código, um pdf, etc.

Com isso temos varias ferramentas com o projeto, por exemplo, restaurar arquivos excluídos em qualquer etapa do projeto, decidir o código usar no caso de dois programadores modificarem o mesmo arquivo.

Hoje temos uma muito utilizada e totalmente gratuita, o Git.

"GIT é uma ferramenta de versionamento amplamente utilizada em projetos com grande número de colaboradores, sem contar que é a plataforma na qual roda o GITHUB, serviço online que provê um servidor GIT gratuito para projetos opensource. Assim sendo, este será a ferramenta utilizada no projeto."

Se ainda não conhece, remendo dar uma olhada nesse artigo do próprio site do Git https://github.com/MuvucaGames/Tutoriais/wiki/%5BWIP%5D-Tutorial-completo-sobre-versionamento-com-GIT.